# Floor floor floor inside another floor

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Inspired from [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97891/x-x-x-x-2020)

$$
\aleph(x,n)=\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x...\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor\
$$

where $\aleph$ is the inner floor function with $n$ times for $x$. For example;

$$
\aleph(x,3)=\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor\
$$

or

$$
\aleph(x,1)=\lfloor x\rfloor
$$

so from the previous question we know that;

if 
$$
\aleph(x,3)=\frac{2020}{x}
$$
then 
$$
x=-\frac{2020}{305}
$$

so this time the question is

> What is the maximum value of $n$ with the minimum value $x$ such that a solution exists if the same question is asked without the value of $n$ given?

such as;

$$
\aleph(x,n)=\frac{2020}{x}
$$

---

For example;
if 
$$
\aleph(x,9)=\frac{2020}{x}
$$
then there is solution such as:
$$
x=-\frac{2020}{979}
$$

but this is not maximum value of $n$.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. Are you asking for the maximum value of $n$ such that a solution exists?

Comment: Nice extension but it would be handier to define ℵ(x) as x⌊x⌊x⌊x...⌋⌋⌋.

Comment: I did misread $\aleph()$ as $x\lfloor\ldots\rfloor$ at first
but now appreciate how it is always an integer (especially as $\aleph$ visually resembles **N**)

Comment: @Xi'an my intention was to give a small hint in the question by seperating last $x$ multiplication from the function.

Comment: Such a nice and neat original variation on the 4-floor puzzle. Daunting at first glance, this turns out to need no calculator or trial-and-error, just a willingness to start at the extremes of possibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The maximum $n$, its smallest $x$ and the equality now satisfied are**:**
$ \require{begingroup}\begingroup
   \def \a        #1#2{ {\aleph} \!\!\: \left( {#1} , {#2} \right) }
    \def \b         #1{ {#1}\d{#1} }
     \def \d        #1{ {\large{{#1} \over 2019}} }
      \def \e         { {\!\;\varepsilon} }
       \def \f      #1{ \left\lfloor {#1} \right\rfloor }
        \def \l       { \\[.3ex] }
         \def \x      { {\-\b1} }
          \def \xd    { {\-\!\:\d{2020}} }
           \def \xp   { {\big( \x \big)} }
            \def \. #1{ {\,{#1}\,} }
             \def \-  { {\scriptsize \raise.25ex -} }
              \def \+ { {\scriptsize \phantom    +} }
               \def \={ \kern-.3em & \kern-.3em = \kern-.3em & \kern-.3em  }
$

> \begin{array}{rcccccc}        n  \= \+4035                 \\[1ex]        x  \=   \xd  \= \-\b{1} \\[2ex]  \a{x}{n} \= \-2019 \= {\Large{ 2020 \over \-\,\LARGE{2020\over2019}~ }}           \= \Large{2020 \over \Large \raise.3ex x} \end{array}

This solution uses the recurrence relation
$\a{x}{i{+}1} = \f{x\,\a{x}{i}}$
observed in the definition
$ \a{x}{i} = \underbrace{\f{x\,\f{x\,\f{...\f{x}}}}}
                       _{\large \f{~i~\sf levels~}} $. 
Here is how $x\,\a{x}{n} = 2020$ is reached**:**

> \begin{matrix}  \a{x}{1}    \= \f{x          }    \= \f{\x      }   \= \-2 \l  \a{x}{2}    \= \f{x\,\a{x}{1}}    \= \f{\+\b{2}}    \= \+2  \l  \a{x}{3}    \= \f{x\,\a{x}{2}}    \= \f{\-\b{2}}    \= \-3   \l  \a{x}{4}    \= \f{x\,\a{x}{3}}    \= \f{\+\b{3} }   \= \+3    \\[-.3ex]            &\vdots&              &\vdots&          &\vdots&     \\  \a{x}{4033} \= \f{x\,\a{x}{4032}} \= \f{\-\b{2017}} \= \-2018   \l  \a{x}{4034} \= \f{x\,\a{x}{4033}} \= \f{\+\b{2018}} \= \+2018    \l  \a{x}{4035} \= \f{x\,\a{x}{4034}} \= \f{\-\b{2018}} \= \-2019     \\[2ex] \hline \raise1ex\strut \boldsymbol{x\,\a{x}{n}}              \=    x\,\a{x}{4035}  \= \xp(\-2019)    \= \boldsymbol{2020} \end{matrix}

**For this solution the goal is taken to approach
  $~ \a{x}{i} = \large{2020 \over \large \raise.3ex x} ~$
  as gradually as possible.**
This suggests examining values of $x$
that border between progressing and getting stuck
along the recurrence relation $\a{x}{i{+}1} = \f{x\,\a{x}{i}}$.

It seems obvious that $\a{x}{i}$ should not overshoot 2020 for $i \.< n$
and that, for minimal progress, $x$ should be as close as possible to 0.
The puzzle statement’s example of $\a{\-{2020\over979}}{9}$
opens the way for $x \.< 0$
but it is easier to get a feel for the puzzle with $x \.> 0$.

**What is the smallest positive value of $x$ that does not get stuck?**
It is $x \.= 2$, as demonstrated in comparison to $1 \.\le x \.< 2$.

\begin{array}{rclcrcl}
 \a{2}{1} \= \f{2}      && \a{x}{1} \= \f{x} \kern1em\textsf{for$~~1\le x<2$} \\
          \= 2          &&          \= 1                             \\[1.5ex]
 \a{2}{2} \= \f{2\f{2}} && \a{x}{2} \= \f{x\f{x}}                     \l
          \=   4        &&          \= \f{(x)(1)}                      \\
 \small \textsf{(doubles from}~\rlap{\textsf{$\a{2}{1}$ to $\a{2}{2}$)}}
&&                      &\kern3em&  \= 1                                 \\
&& && &     \small\llap {\textsf{(stuck at}}~\rlap{\textsf{$\a{x}{1}$)}}
 \end{array}

For this smallest positive candidate of $x \. = 2$,
$~ \a{2}{i} $ grows exponentially to $\a{2}{11} = 2048$,
which is too much,
meaning that $n{=}10$ would be the largest possibility for $n$
if $x$ is some difficult-to-pin-down number near 2.

**What, then, is the smallest (closest to zero)
  *negative* value of $x$ that does not get stuck?**
It is $x = \-1{-}\e$ with an infinitesimally positive $\e$,
as demonstrated in comparison to $x \.= \-1$.

\begin{array}{rclcrcl}
\a{\-1{-}\e}{1} \= \f{\-1{-}\e} && \a{\-1}{1} \= \f{\-1} \\
                \= \-2          &&            \= \-1      \\[1.5ex]
\a{\-1{-}\e}{3} \= \f{(\-1{-}\e)\f{(\-1{-}\e)\f{\-1{-}\e}}}
                                && \a{\-1}{3} \= \f{(\-1)\f{(\-1)\f{\-1}}} \l
 \= \f{(\-1{-}\e)\f{(\-1{-}\e)(-2)}}  &&      \= \f{(\-1)(1)}               \l
 \= \f{(\-1{-}\e)\f{2{+}2\e}} &\kern1em&      \= \-1                         \l
 \= \f{(\-1{-}\e)(2)}                 &&
              & \small\llap{\textsf{(stuck at}}~\rlap{\textsf{$\a{\-1}{1}$)}} \l
 \= \f{\-2{-}2\e}                                                            \\
 \= \-3                                                                       \\
 \small \textsf {($\,$increments by}
 ~\rlap{\textsf{$\-1$ from $\, \a{\-1{-}\e}{1} \,$ to $\, \a{\-1{-}\e}{3} \,$)}}
\end{array}

Pursuing this candidate of $x = \-1{-}\e$ works as well as could be hoped!
Not only is the progression of $\a{x}{i}$ linear rather than exponential
but it also grows at only half the rate of $i$,
as laid out for the solution’s $x$ near the top of this answer.
All that remains is to choose an $x$ near −1
so that $x \, \a{x}{n} = 2020$.

> Although $~ \a{\-1{-}\e}{4037} = \-2020 ~$
>  looks promising, it is too good to be true because
>  $~ (\-1{-}\e)\,\a{\-1{-}\e}{4037} = 2020{+}2020\e > 2020 ~$
>  overshoots the target.
>  
>  Thus, using $n \.= 4035$ and working from
>  $~ \a{\-1{-}\e}{4035} = \-2019 ~$
>  means solving for $~ x = \-1{-}h ~$ in
>  $~ (\-1{-}h)\,\a{\-1{-}h}{4035} = 2019{+}2019h = 2020 \,$.
>  And there it is, $\, h \.= \d{1} \,$ so $\, x \.= \-\b{1} \,$.

$\endgroup$